# I want to include Solaimanlipi font in my TCPDF. Do u have any idea?

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf, indic

The Bangla Unicode font (**Solaimanlipi**) is one of most complicated font. Basically it have some complex combination e.g. ক্ষ ঙ্ক ঙ্গ জ্ঞ ঞ্চ ঞ্ছ ঞ্জ ত্ত ষ্ণ হ্ম ণ্ড কো etc.

Please help me to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your font like this.

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/yourfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

after that you can set your font like this...

```
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
```

**`TCPDF`** documentation gives you clear explanation for this. See [`here`](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php)